# Can`t connect to IRC Server: Closing Link (Install identd)

Tags: linux, debian, connection, irc, xchat

I installed a Hybrid-IRC Server on my linux Vserver.
If i try to connect to my IRC Server with Xchat i get this: "Closing Link (Install identd)", but if i use a online IRC client like kiwiirc.com or i connect to localhost (on the Vserver) it works. I alerady used other IRC client like mIRC, but i got the same error. I think it`s a problem with the server.

I hope you guys can help with this problem :D

Comment: EDIT: Online IRC Clients like kiwiirc.com does not work.

Comment: The error message seems to suggest you should install identd.